# In Person signing request model data [xml] - for remote signing

Tags: docusignapi, docushare

I am working on DocuSign api integration with my application [Rest using xml]. I need to use the In person signing feature. And I am looking for the sample request data [xml] for the envelope including the In person signing tag.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Showji, did my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `inPersonSigner` recipient type there's some extra parameters you need to set (in addition to regular signer params).  For in-person you need to set the `hostName`, `hostEmail`, and `signerName` recipient parameters, with the `signerEmail` being optional.

If using DocuSign REST API + XML format here's what the request looks like:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
    <emailSubject>DocuSign API:  In-Person Signing Test</emailSubject>
    <documents>
      <document>
        <name>Test.pdf</name>
        <documentId>1</documentId>
      </document>
    </documents>
    <recipients>
        <inPersonSigners>
            <inPersonSigner>
                <hostName>John Doe</hostName>
                <hostEmail>johndoe@email.com</hostEmail>
                <signerName>Sally Doe</signerName>
                <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
                <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                <tabs>
                    <signHereTabs>
                      <signHereTab>
                        <xPosition>100</xPosition>
                        <yPosition>100</yPosition>
                        <documentId>1</documentId>
                        <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                      </signHereTab>
                    </signHereTabs>
                </tabs>
            </inPersonSigner>    
        </inPersonSigners>
    </recipients>
    <status>sent</status>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

And if using DocuSign REST API + JSON format you can use this:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign API:  In-Person Signing Test",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Test.pdf"
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "inPersonSigners": [{
            "hostName": "John Doe",
            "hostEmail": "johndoe@email.com",
            "signerName": "Sally Doe",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "xPosition": "100",
                    "yPosition": "100",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1"
                }]
            }
        }]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```